# CoAP and MQTT support in Wildfly 8.0.0.Final

Tags: wildfly, mqtt, wildfly-8, coap

We have an enterprise solution deployed on Wildfly 8.0.0 server, we intend to support CoAP and MQTT also as communication protocol. We explored extensively but we couldn't find even any oblique reference to our problem case. Is it possible to add CoAP and MQTT support without destabilizing  Wildfly setup ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think theoretically it is possible to use a https://www.eclipse.org/californium/ within an EE server for CoAP.

The main issue here is that Californium listens to an UDP port (and sends datagrams too).
So if you want to stay within a EE specification, you'll have to implement a JCA adapter for that.
If you want things to just work, you can run/manage it from a JMX bean.

Answer (score 1):

WildFly being a Web Server doesn't necessarily need to support CoAP or MQTT because those are not standard HTTP based Communication protocols but protocols designed to enable M2M (Machine to Machine) Communication.

As of WildFly 8.0.0.Final it only allows HTTP (Servlet, JAX-RS, JAX-WS), Web Sockets, HTTP Upgraded Remoting (EJB Invocation, Remote JNDI).