# EJB handling in CoAP server?

Tags: java, http, ejb, iot, coap

We have our application backend deployed on wildfly-8, using EJB (Enterprise Java Bean) technology and it's catering HTTP requests. Now we need to support CoAP requests too, with using our same backend. Unfortunately wildfly has no CoAP support.

We are using Californium CoAP server now, but we are not able to use our same backend code using EJB's on the CoAP server.

The only feasible solution we have come to is doing a remote EJB lookup from CoAP server to wildfly server.

Any pointers to be able to use our EJB backed backend for CoAP request too ?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to answer to similar question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47967481/3323777

I suppose (very raw guess) you would end up with Message Driven Beans anyway.